# Sum involving prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Given the series:
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{k}{p_k}$$
where $p_k$ is the $k^{th}$ prime number, is it possible to know if this series converges in the limit:
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}S$$
and eventually, its numerical value?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sum diverges rather quickly, with $S \approx N/\log N$.  Did you have a reason to expect it to converge?

Comment: @Erick Wong: No, I don't. So the answer seems to be very simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of inverse primes itself is divergent (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes)), so no the series does not converge.

Answer (score 1):

From the prime number theorem
$$
\pi(x) = \frac{x}{\log x} + O\left(\frac{x}{(\log x)^2}\right) \qquad (x \to \infty)
$$
one can deduce that
$$
p_k \sim k \log k \qquad (k \to \infty),
$$
which allows you to employ the limit comparison test on your sum.